# Hand cursor type on report Groups

Tags: crystal-reports

How can I change to the Hand cursor while the mouse is hovering over the group headings in the CR Viewer? I am using using Crystal Reports 2011 that ships with Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Maybe with some javascript, if you look up the html that is generated by your CrystalReportViewer on your webpage. You can found your FieldObject with their ID , dynamically generated but they will all have the same beginning name

Comment: I have seen a class object drill_cursor where pointer image is dynamically generated, but while overriding the cursor property in same class, there is no change.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this behavior [isn't definable within Crystal Reports](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dcb137d5-a461-4361-962c-af35545ba34f/cursor-type-on-crystal-report-viewer?forum=vscrystalreports), including the Viewer. The only way I know to create a Hand cursor in Crystal is to turn the text into a hyperlink.

[image]

If you're trying to indicate that an area is clickable, you'll have to do it some other way. (You could make the header text blue and underlined to make it appear like a hyperlink.) Or you could just include some "Click to Focus" text. But sadly the cursor isn't something Crystal allows you to define.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.